# How to select one item of ListView in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I am a newbie in React-Native. I want to select one item using ListView. When I first press item, the ListView renderRow() was call, But after all not working！How can I fix this bug? My problem is where?

I wrote a demo in [here](https://gist.github.com/devyu/d855e1bf4eac9d9e2ee14c4c103a9923)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up setting empty dataSource initially, then setting it to clone with data variable in componentDidMount. Then, in the onPressRow method, I made the required changes to a copy of data state variable and then set it back to data via setState method. Not sure what your problem was, but this is working now.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

class ListViewDemo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      data: this._genRow(),
      dataSource: ds,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.data)
    });
  }

  _genRow(){
    var datas = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      datas.push({
        row: i,
        isSelect: false,
      });
    }
    console.log('datas ' + JSON.stringify(datas));
    return datas;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow = {this._renderRow.bind(this)}
        renderHeader = {() => <View style={{height: 10, backgroundColor:     '#f5f5f5'}} />}
        onEndReached = {() => console.log('')}
        renderSeparator = {(sectionID, rowID) =>
          <View
            style={styles.style_separator}
            key={`${sectionID} - ${rowID}`}
          />}
      />
    );
  }

  _renderRow(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
    console.log('render row ...');
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressRow.bind(this.rowID, rowData)}>
        <View style={styles.style_row_view}>
          <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.row}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.isSelect ? 'true' : 'false'}                   </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      }

  _onPressRow(rowID, rowData) {

    rowData.isSelect = !rowData.isSelect;
    var dataClone = this.state.data;
    dataClone[rowID] = rowData;
    this.setState({
      data: dataClone
    });
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  style_row_view: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 57,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  style_text: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 12,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#333333',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ListViewDemo', () => ListViewDemo);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, solved my problem! I made a mistake! I should setState()  when _onPressRow() the row.

Comment: setting state directly w/o using setState was one issue yes

Comment: Yes, I accepted this answer yesterday. thank you again.

Comment: `this._onPressRow.bind(this.rowID, rowData)` I guess here you meant to pass `this` and `rowId`, not `this.rowId`

Comment: <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressRow.bind(this.rowID, rowData)}>
Using bind will create a new function every time it re-renders and it will cause performance issue. 

Better change to
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
   this._onPressRow(this.rowID, rowData)
}}>

Comment: I've made it, but wonder why we need to input empty datasource at first for get it working? I've tried set datasource != empty and setState after touch but didn't get the row refresh

Comment: @IrfanAyaz I am getting error msg while adding the above code : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.data')

Answer (score -1):

try calling the function like this
onPress={(obj1,obj2) => this._onPressRow(rowID, rowData)}